# Processing randomly distributed experimental data using ks_2samp in scipy

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I have two different sets of randomly distributed experimental data. I have to check weather both are from same data set or not. I wish to apply 2 sample KS test using scipy in python.

I don't understand how to pass both sequences of data in function `ks_2samp`.

`scipy.stats.ks_2samp(data1, data2)`

Can anyone explain what is data1 and data2? Can I directly pass my data using sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

dataset1 = np.random.randn(100)  #random distribution
dataset2 = np.random.randn(100) 

res = stats.ks_2samp(dataset1, dataset2)

print res
```

Your result is the something like:

```
(0.089999999999999969, 0.79418377128477335)
```

Comment: I have al ready two data set. i need not produce new data set.Can i pass my data set directly to function ks_2samp

Comment: I made two datasets only to illustrate how to pass them to the function!

Comment: My result for two data set having length 35 is : (0.028571428571428581, 0.99999999999999989)

I am not understabding this result exactly according to this link

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html